# What does the command CD do?

Tags: macos, unix, freebsd

Not realising I had caps-lock on, I typed `CD` into the command prompt on my mac.  Surprisingly, it didn't error.

`which CD` shows me `/usr/bin/CD`.  And if I examine that file, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19 cperciva Exp $
# This file is in the public domain.
builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

I guess it's something to do with translating upper to lower case, but `${0##*/}` is completely opaque to me.  `man CD` tells me "no manual entry".  Can someone explain this command?

EDIT: Ok, I just noticed that OSX's filesystem is case-insensitive, so this file is actually `/usr/bin/cd`.  But if I type `cd` normally, I of course get the builtin, so `/usr/bin/cd` only gets called when I get my case wrong.  I'd still like to know what it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems it doesn't do much at all:

[Apple mailing list link](http://web.archive.org/web/20150513110652/http://lists.apple.com/archives/Darwin-userlevel/2005/May/msg00031.html)

> "I'm going on some old memories here, so I cannot provide a very
>   detailed explanation, but the reason /usr/bin/cd exists is due
>   to a POSIX requirement that relates to aliases and being able to
>   not use an alias via escaping.  But /usr/bin/cd is a useless
>   script since if you run cd within a shell script the directory
>   change only applies to the subshell under which the script runs.
>   cd cannot be a shell script.
>
> Also, the script is a generic script in that it is used for a
>   number of commands and not just cd.
>
> I noticed that `/usr/bin/cd` has a hard link count of 15 on my
>   10.4 system [...]"

Further down in that thread:

> "A friend of mine told me the "${0##*/}" means "take the command, but remove its path" (i.e., convert "/usr/bin/cd" to "cd")."

So it seems the script removes the path, converts the result to lower case and then appends the original arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to do the right thing and translate your "cd" command to lowercase.  Regrettably, that's pretty pointless as it runs in a subshell.  The remainder has to do with understanding bash.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then it doesn't work! If I type, e.g., `CD /`, it just does nothing.

Comment: That's because it runs in a subshell; the subshell cd's to /, then exits, leaving *your* shell unmoved.

Comment: As has been pointed out, this same script has a number of different filenames (hard links) - most if not all of them are UPPERCASE filenames.   YES - in the case of CD it doesn't appear to work because cd has no effect when run in a subshell.  That's why I wrote that it's "trying" to do the right thing.  Indeed, it does not succeed.   For SOME cases, this script will do the right thing; for example, if it's linked to LS, when you type "LS /USR/BIN" it will run "ls /usr/bin"

Comment: Also, those aren't regular expressions.  They're Bash parameter expansions: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion